# Rejected transaction shows up on etherscan says 0 spend approved 0 gas approved yet 29,400 usdc is in the transaction revoking changed landing return?

Tags: solidity

Rejected transaction shows up on etherscan says 0 spend approved 0 gas approved yet 29,400 usdc is in the transaction revoke removed remarks i need  to get back before the revoke i diod not get a screen shot as i did not know revoke would change the landing page, Somehow when I straight rejected a transaction there was a proxy spend forged i need to find how i can get back to that to prove this PLEASEE help so I go to ((( this is hash landing after revoke    0xdf1947ffb0cd3861e69fd91cf5a5b397a60e530490151ca803f9e5c195131c8e ))))
I go here to verify proxy its not verified so how can they get my money https://etherscan.io/proxycontractchecker?a=0x41e8a9188136cf26bda9bd33acbfd0bc808a025b
I think this shows but i dont know how to read it that there is zero spend https://ethtx.info/mainnet/0xdf1947ffb0cd3861e69fd91cf5a5b397a60e530490151ca803f9e5c195131c8e/
Proxy Contract Verification Page
×
The proxy contract verification completed with the message:

The implementation contract at 0xce0f0395dd9f9aabc725d1f0654f09489d508988 does not seem to be verified.
Please verify and publish the contract source before proceeding with this proxy verification. then i click 0xce0f0395dd9f9aabc725d1f0654f09489d508988 seems to say not payable, code that allows forged proxy spend I see no excuse or defence for any the landing page was very clear origionally i only got there through my tax tracker that said i may have a taxable situation because of an airdrop or this would not have happened

Comment: Unfortunately there's nothing you could do. At some point you have approved the phishing contract (`0x41e8a918..`) to use the USDC tokens in your address.

Then at the transaction `0xdf1947ff..` the attacker called the phishing contract to transfer USDC to an address he controls.

Comment: If thats true how did it say on etherscan that this transaction was approved for 0 spend and 0 gas???

Comment: Where does it say *approved for 0 spend and 0 gas*? I don't see that message in the transaction details.

Comment: It said it before i clicked revoke once i clicked revoke onchain it shows the little guy symbol going online and approving it but the only approval was a revoke however I believe since it is all supposed to be immutable it has to be in the code somewhere and with a evm sandbox which i am trying to figure out should be able to show all states of the transaction.

Comment: OK I can show from tools on blockchair the transaction shows 0 $ and zero gas I will link that single transaction in the block I am sure with a click or 2 you can see the rest of the block then there is a tool at

Comment: I show from tools on blockchair https://blockchair.com/ethereum/transactions?s=id(asc)&q=block_id(15872768),id(15872768000027)#f=hash,block_id,failed,time,sender,recipient,internal_value,id,value_usd 0 $ and zero gas block  sandbox tool at  https://3xpl.com/api/docs/#/Common/search run transaction sandbox clearly shows unauthorized transaction but even better blockchair shows the value of gas and value of transaction as 0 evidence showed up at etherscan before I revoke said transaction approved for 0 spend and zero gas if phished or they had my keys it would show up with value forged transact

Comment: Sorry, but the transaction had been mined Nov-01-2022 04:19:59 AM +UTC. It is impossible to reverse it. In PoS Ethereum transactions are final after 32 blocks. The message about revoking a transaction perhaps was something your wallet showed before the transaction was mined, but the opportunity is long gone.

Comment: dOES THIS BLOCHCHAIR PROVE MY ISSUE OR NOT? i AM POSITIVE WHAT HAPPENED AND A forged proxy spend was once an issue on POW I think someone found a vulnerability on eth merge and should be fixed before someone looses 100million$ or something https://blockchair.com/ethereum/transactions?s=id(asc)&q=block_id(15872768),id(15872768000027)#f=hash,block_id,failed,time,sender,recipient,internal_value,value_usd,id
2022-11-01 04:19:59 I also ran it in a sandbox and the sandbox said it was not an approved contract.

Comment: The blockchair link has the same information than the etherscan link. It doesn't have additional details. I'm not an expert on USDC contract code. You should contact their creator if you think you found a bug.

Comment: When a transaction on a number of evm's says it is an invalid contract and unverified implementation code there is no argument or defence for allowing it to process this is crap code , I have to learn all this because there is no one that takes responsibility , interest or anything. who is responcible for this code that allows invalid contracts on the chain?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help you with that. Contract verification is done off-chain. The EVM is never aware of a contract verified status. Also a verified contract isn't warranty that it will behave correctly, search for honey-pot contract. I suggest to contact your local authorities to denounce the scam/fraud with the smart contract. They are the only ones that can help locating the perpetrators.